# What is the most efficient way of retrieving a single item from Outlook (interop)

Tags: c#, interop, outlook

I need to create a program that synchronizes it's own task objects to tasks in outlook.  During the operation, tasks in outlook may be created/updated/deleted.

The most straightforward way is to iterate over all task items in outlook, looking for which ones to update.  Very roughly:

```
ApplicationClass _app;
NameSpace _nameSpace;
MAPIFolder _folder;

_app = new ApplicationClass();
_nameSpace = _app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
_folder = _nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);

Dictionary<int,MyTask> data = GetData();

for (int i = 1; i <= _folder.Items.Count; i++)
{
    TaskItem taskItem = (TaskItem)_folder.Items.Item(i);
    int itemID;
    if(ItemNeedsProcessing(taskItem, out itemID))
        UpdateItem(taskItem, data[itemID]);
}
```

But this could possibly iterate through hundreds of items (*depending on the client's outlook task history*), just to make one or two changes.

Alternatively, I could track the `ItemID` of the task...

```
string itemID = "00000000873..."; //taken from property on object.
object o = _nameSpace.GetItemFromID(itemID); //ignore possible exceptions for now
TaskItem taskItem = (TaskItem)o;
```

... and update it directly (*which complicates the creation/deletion of tasks on the application side somewhat*).

Is retrieving the task item directly (`GetItemFromID`) the most efficient way? Or is there some pitfall I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outlook 2007+ added [`Folder.GetTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.gettable.aspx) which optimizes the retrieval using a lightweight approach in comparison to [`Folder.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff864247.aspx). Using **Tables** [can be up to 10x faster](http://books.google.com/books?id=DnxuBDWM9E4C&pg=PT856&lpg=PT856&dq=outlook%20gettable%2010%20times%20faster%20items&source=bl&ots=-HuR7tZOW9&sig=2RlYfvF83NkxWWm5RENsVfHCuDo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=U5nYT6qEC46E8ASP842rAw&ved=0CE8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=outlook%20gettable%2010%20times%20faster%20items&f=false) than an **Items** iterator.

As for retrieving the actual item, [`Session.GetItemFromID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._namespace.getitemfromid%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is the fastest way to retrieve an item - especially if you pass in the [`Store.StoreID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._store.storeid) as a secondary parameter so Outlook doesn't have to determine which **Store** a particular `EntryID` belongs to.

```cs
const string PR_STORE_ENTRYID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0FFB0102";
Outlook.Table tasks = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks).GetTable();
tasks.Columns.Add(PR_STORE_ENTRYID); // optimal for GetItemFromID
while (!tasks.EndOfTable)
{
    Outlook.Row task = tasks.GetNextRow();
    Outlook.TaskItem item = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(task["EntryID"], task.BinaryToString(PR_STORE_ENTRYID)) as Outlook.TaskItem;
}
```

As for best approach - you should track the **Task EntryID** and **Task StoreID** in the application if you wanted to minimize sync execution time. Otherwise, the brute force approach of retrieving all tasks would work, but I'd recommend using `Folder.GetTable()` instead of using `Folder.Items`.

Comment: Excellent answer! My constraint is to be compatible with Outlook 2003 and up... so I can't use the GetTable method just yet.
Using the StoreID seems to be the best method for now.

Answer (score 1):

Building on SliverNinja’s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11016129/1149773), my recommendation would be to use the Outlook Redemption [RDO Library](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm). It’s a third-party commercial tool, but it would allow you to use [`MAPITable`](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/mapitable.htm) in Outlook 2003 (and above).

Comment: Also good, but I was hoping for something native rather than involve a 3rd party library (not that I have anything against 3rd party libs).